# AWS EC2 - Cloudera Manager- Stopping instances

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, cloudera

I have setup the hadoop cluster on Amazon EC2 using cloudera manager. Cloudera manager created two instances and all is working as expected. I am trying to stop the cloudera created instances through AWS console but there is no option to stop. We have only "Terminate" and "Reboot". I don't want to terminate these instances as  i want to reuse these instances.

How to stop these instances ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your instances came from an instance-store backed AMI you will only be able to reboot and terminate the instances. Look in the Management Console under "root device" to confirm this is the case.

To get around this, you can create an AMI from your instances then restart your environment using the new AMI which would give you the option to stop your instances.

Comment: Yes, I have verified the root device and it is "Instance Store" rather than "ebs". Is there any simple way of changing the root device to "ebs" from "Instance Store" ?

Comment: Right click on your instance. Can you select "Create Image (EBS AMI)"?

Comment: "Create Image(EBS AMI)" is disabled.

Comment: Then you'll have to go for the more tedious option! I suggest referencing [Alex M's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082724/amazon-ec2-swap-root-instance-store-device-with-ebs-device) to a similar problem.

Comment: UPDATE: After reading a little more, you might want to take [this information](http://grokbase.com/t/cloudera/scm-users/133knc0rna/deploy-ebs-backed-ec2-cluster) into consideration.